# Tweeting a variable or a html classes contents - Random Quote Machine - freeCodeCamp

Tags: javascript, html, twitter

I'm relatively new to JavaScript. I'm working on the freeCodeCamp - "Random Quote Machine". And trying to tweet a variable and or html .class.

My code thus far: [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/ajukco/pen/ppLgpX)

```
$('#tweet').click(function()window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=' + quote, '_blank');});
```

I hope someone could give me a hint as to what I am doing incorrectly. It currently returns "undefined" in the new tweet. I know this probably means my **var** isn't properly defined but struggling to figure out why that is.

Comment: what do you expect `var quote = quote;` to be doing?

Comment: your function syntax is incorrect. missing an opening {

Comment: also you're click function is wrapped inside your get quote click handler in your codepen

Comment: also var quote = quote; is trying to assign quote to an undefined variable

Comment: You need to assign your `quote` var to the data returned by the AJAX call when the "get quote" click happens, not to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you quote variable must look like:

```
var quote = $('.quote')[0].children[0].innerText;
```

Also you can put id to that paragraph to can take the innerText directly.